# NodeJS template literal with async map

Tags: node.js, template-literals

I'm trying to generate an HTML content using template literal because I need to loop through an array. It is not returning the map content to the template literal.

```
const htmlData = `
                <html>
                    ... // Some content here

                    <table class="table table-bordered" style="width: 800px;" align="center">
                        <thead class="thead-light">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Company</th>
                                <th>Bill Date</th>
                                <th>Billing Days</th>
                                <th>Total Units</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            ${customers.map( async (customer) => {
                                let units = 0;
                                const companyDate = new Date(customer.CompanyStartDate);
                                const billDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), companyDate.getDate());
                                const numDays = (today.getTime() - billDate.getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
                                const pData = await property.getPropTotalUnitsByCompany(customer.CompanyID);
                                return (
                                    `
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            ${pData.map(async (propData) => {
                                                units += propData.TotalUnits;
                                                return (
                                                    `
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-sm-12" align="right">
                                                            Property: ${propData.PropertyName} Total Units: ${propData.TotalUnits}
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    `
                                                );
                                            })}
                                        </td>
                                        <td>${myFunctions.formatDisplayDate(billDate)}</td>
                                        <td>${numDays}</td>
                                        <td>${units}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    `
                                );
                            })}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    ... // More content here
            </html> 
            `;
```

It returns [object Promise] inside my . Here is where I have the .map(). Can't I use map in template literals?

Thank you

Comment: Probably that is due to the fact that the promise is not yet resolved. Just looking at your code, if this is server side rendered page, I'd rather use something like [Pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html). Or even use a frontend framework such as [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/). These tools help you a lot for this kind of tasks.

Comment: It is a server side. However, it is a CRON job that generates a HTML content that is convert to PDF and sent by email. How can I wait to resolve the promise?

Comment: I've just noticed an `async (propData) => ...` without anything being `await`ed inside that arrow function. Have you tried removing that `async`? About waiting for the promise to be resolved, I think that everything is handled by `async/await` construct. Check this [guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)

Comment: Yes, I tried, but still same issue. It looks like it is not waiting to resolve the map promise

Comment: Why in the first place are you using `async/await`? Is `getPropTotalUnitsByCompany` an async function?

Comment: If that function is not an `async` function, remove those async and await keywords from your code and see if that resolves.

Comment: Yes, getPropTotalUnitsByCompany is an async function. I get data from the database

Comment: It looks like it is not waiting to finish the map() method

Comment: I see, well, I don't know how to help you because I don't have the full picture about those objects and methods called in your code. However, if you let me, I suggest you to double check everything and understand deeply how the result is generated from your code and its relation with async await.

Comment: @myTest532 myTest532
Did you ever find a solution for this? I´m running into the same issue.